# Kill joblib code in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, joblib

I have used `joblib` module in `python 3.6.0` to parallelize my code and ran it on my Linux machine. It has now started the process on 20 threads, as expected. But I am unable to kill all of them at once. For instance, if I kill any of the same 20 processes in `matlab`, the whole thing gets killed. Is there any such way in python 3?

EDIT: My code looks something like this

```
import scipy, numpy     # All the required libraries
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
# Required parameters
a=1
b=2 ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parallel(n_jobs=20)(delayed(<some_function>)((a,b,j)) for j in range(20))
```

The `some_function` uses the parameters and saves using `scipy.savetxt` command.

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I have added the code in my question.